# Unable to link libpng or zlib in Eclipse with MinGW C linker

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, static-libraries, libpng

I'm new to external static libraries in C, and i'm having trouble adding pnglib (or any library) to Eclipse. Im using Eclipse v3.3.2 with mingw on windows 7 64bit.

I first followed these instructions to install libpng and zlib: http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_MinGW

Then in Eclipse under **C/C++ Build** -> **Settings** ->**Tool Settings** -> **MinGW C Linker** -> **Libraries**

I added: **"png"** then **"z"** in Libraries (-l)

and: **"C:\MinGW\libpng-1.5.12"** then **"C:\MinGW\zlib-1.2.7"** in the Library search path (-L)

If I execute the simplest code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <png.h>

int main(void) {        

    printf("foo\n");

    unsigned char header[8];
    //png_sig_cmp(header, 0, 0);    

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine, however as soon as i uncomment the function, the code compiles (without error/warning), but does absolutely nothing, (not even the print statement). This happens when I use ANY function from an external library.

I assume it can read the headers but there's funny business with finding function definitions.

I have no idea where i went wrong.

I'm sure I have missed something trivial!

Comment: If you double-click the executable from windows explorer I would expect a message box to appear stating it could not find a DLL required by the application. I have seen this behaviour in cygwin, which appears to suppress this message box and reports no error. To correct, add the directory that contains the DLL to your `PATH`.

Comment: The dependency walker - http://www.dependencywalker.com is pretty awesome for checking if you've linked to a static library or a dynamic linker in this case; there's a good chance that it's trying to use `.dll` files that are not in the path of the binary

Comment: Thanks so much! Adding it to the Windows Path and then restarting Eclipse fixed everything :) never would have found that on my own.